Pdfmake got border display error when have rowspan with a too long data in angular 9
I'm using pdfmake to generate PDFs in Angular.
I'm encountering a display issue as shown in the attached image.
When there is a row with rowspan in a table, and the row with rowspan contains at least one column with a value that is too long for the current page, the issue occurs as shown in the image.
Please help me resolve this problem!
enter image description here
this is my docDefinition json
{"widths":["8%","10%","10%","9%","9%","9%","9%","9%","9%","9%","9%"],"body":[[{"text":"STT","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Tên nhà thầu","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Mã số thuế","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Giá dự thầu (VND)","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Giá dự thầu sau hiệu chỉnh sai lệch thừa (nếu c sai lệch thừa (nếu có), á dự thầu sau hiệu chỉnh sai lệch thừa (nếu có), giảm giá (nếu có) (VND)","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Điểm kỹ thuật (nếu có)","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Giá đánh giá (nếu có) (VND)","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Giá trúng thầu (VND)","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Thời gian thực hiện gói thầu","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Thời gian thực hiện hợp đồng","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"},{"text":"Các nội dung khác (nếu có)","fontSize":11,"style":"tableHeader"}],[{"text":1,"fontSize":11,"rowSpan":7,"style":""},{"text":"Liên danh bảo hiểm Tổ hợp bauxit - nhôm Lâm Đồng","fontSize":11,"rowSpan":7,"style":""},{"text":"9876543219","fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":"1.071.031.727","rowSpan":7,"fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","rowSpan":7,"fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","rowSpan":7,"fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","rowSpan":7,"fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":"1.071.031.727","rowSpan":7,"fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":"365 ngày kể từ 0 giờ 00 phút ngày 01/01/2025 đến 24 giờ 00 phút ngày 31/12/2025","rowSpan":7,"fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":"Giá dự thầu sau hiệu chỉnh sai lệch thừa (nếu có), á dự thầu sau hiệu chỉnh  thầu sau hiệu chỉnh sai lệch thừa (nếu có), giảm giá (nếu có) (VND)Giá dự thầu sau hiệu chỉnh sai lệch thừa (nếu có), á dự thầu sau  lệch thừa (nếu có), giảm giá (nếu có) (VND)","rowSpan":7,"fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","rowSpan":7,"fontSize":11,"style":""}],[{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":"0967722385","fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]}],[{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":"0967722386","fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]}],[{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":"0912348085","fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]}],[{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":"0912348086","fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]}],[{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":"9876543214","fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]}],[{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":"9876543215","fontSize":11,"style":""},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]},{"text":" ","border":[false,false,false,false]}]],"preserveLeadingSpaces":true}

